# Usage of the particle に

Tags: grammar, particle-に

Is this sentence correct?

土曜日'に'何じから何じまで働きますか

I am not sure if I can use the particle に like that. The book asks me to use なんじから なんじまで along with the verb 働きます and the day 土曜日 to form a sentence.should I use は instead of に?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this sentence correct?
>
> 土曜日'に'何じから何じまで働きますか

It feels a bit unnatural.

A sentence such as:

> *あなたは*土曜日**に**働きますか。 : *As of you*, do you work **on** Saturday?

Would be correct because you are directly asking if the person works on Saturday, so the 土曜日 does not have to be the theme of the sentence, the theme is "you" here.

But in your sentence, you already know that the person is going to work on Saturday, you are just asking from when to when. So you cannot just be using the particle に which acts as a direct link between 土曜日 and 働く.
The theme in your sentence should be 土曜日, so instead of に, you should use either には or just は.

> 土曜日には何時から何時まで働きますか。
>
> 土曜日は何時から何時まで働きますか。

Now it is natural.

Since the particle に acts as a direct link between 土曜日 and 働く, you could rephrase your sentence as below:

> 土曜日に働くの**は**、何時から何時までですか。

It should help you figuring out if に only is correct or not.